# Generate Nested Hierarchy response from rails self-referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a self-referential model,

```
class Hierarchy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Hierarchy", :foreign_key => 'parent_id'

  def descendents
    children.map do |child|
      [child] + child.descendents
    end
  end
end
```

How to construct a hierarchal tree from the Model "Hierarchy" like this,

```
{
  "hierarchies": [
    {
      "level": 1, "id": 14951, "name": "EQUIPMENT", "parent_id": null,
      "children": [
        {
          "level": 2, "id": 15040, "name": "BASKETBALL", "parent_id": 14951,
          "children": [
            {
              "level": 3, "id": 15154, "name": "EYEWEAR", "parent_id": 15040,
              "children": [
                {
                  "level": 4, "id": 16617, "name": "OPHTHALMIC", "parent_id": 15154,
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "level": 3, "id": 16417, "name": "OTHER", "parent_id": 15040, "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

"Herarchy" Model's `descendents` method can iterate and retrieve data from the Herarchy model till the last level.

Example:

```
  render :json => { :hierarchies => [root_hierarchy, root_hierarchy.descendents]}
```

It returns all the levels,

```
{
  "hierarchies": [
    {
      "level": 1, "id": 14951, "name": "EQUIPMENT", "parent_id": null
    },
    [
      [
        {
          "level": 2, "id": 15040, "name": "BASKETBALL", "parent_id": 14951
        },
        [
          {
            "level": 3, "id": 15154, "name": "EYEWEAR", "parent_id": 15040
          },
          [
            {
              "level": 4, "id": 16617, "name": "OPHTHALMIC", "parent_id": 15154
            }
          ]
        ],
        [
          {
            "level": 3, "id": 16417, "name": "OTHER", "parent_id": 15040
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

The problem is I couldn't append its associated children in each iteration.
I tried `as_json`, `includes` methods to append the children in its parent object, But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before. I'd recommend you take a look at [closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree). It adds some very helpful methods for operating on hierarchical data. It has a method of grabbing descendants that only requires 1 SELECT query. Your current implementation using an adjacency list is simple, but it requires one query for each descendant, and quickly become inefficient.